# Reconnecting to the kernel Python 3.8

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I get this error when I am running a notebook in VSCode, stuck in the "Reconnecting to the kernel.." message. I DO NOT HAVE the same issue when running a notebook directly inside a browser accessing Jupyter Lab. I am using a Macbook Pro (Apple M1 Pro).

same issue listed here as well https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12775

Why is it stuck, and how can I get it unstuck?

Comment: I got this issue with python39. This happens whenever I tried to display any "graphics" (e.g. PIL image, plt.imshow(img_array). As soon as I ran that line, it will provoke "Reconnecting to the kernel ...." and it will never recover. Not sure if it is related to yours, but any debugging pointers will help. I am new to VS Code.

Comment: I filed a new bug/issue specific to my use case: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13073 hoping someone can help. I think there's something more general going on for apple silicon + vscode + jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at @kawingkelvin's [issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13073),

running the following command from the comments there solved the problem for me!

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install 'jupyter_client<8' 'pyzmq<25' --user --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Please go to the GitHub issue for details and caveats. This pip install will affect your global python packages, and I understood it is a workaround. Later VSCode will have. this fixed promised by one of maintainer.